# Sitecore Change Layout Names

Tags: sitecore, controls, sublayout

Just, I have a quick question.

Suppose that there are many controls in page items and if I change the name of existing layout/sublayouts (controls), does it impact Sitecore items?

In my knowledge, the changing name is in database process and it doesn't touch any physical controls (.ascx) in file system. Even we change the name, the value of ASCX file path field in Sitecore doesn't impact either.

Is it right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the name of the sublayout item without it affecting things.

If you change the actual sublayout ascx file then you need to also change the reference field in the sublayout item but everything else is bound by the id of the item not the name.

Answer (score 2):

Nope it does not impact anything. Reasons-

- A layout set for an item will not be referenced by its name instead it will be referenced by the layout's item id so it does not affect the items using the layout.
- Whenever you change the name of a layout the value of the field containing the address for the ascx file in the file system wont be changed so it does not affect the layout either.